# CodeIgniter validation errors to Ajax print inline

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, validation

I am sending dynamically created form fields to CodeIgniter via ajax.

```
    <div class="form-element">
        <input type="radio" id="delete-radio[1]" name="delete-radio[1]" value="1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="member_id[1]">Membership ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="member_id[1]" name="member_id[]" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo set_value('member_id[1]'); ?>"/>
        <?php echo form_error('member_id[1]', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="member_name[1]">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="member_name[1]" name="member_name[]" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo set_value('member_name[1]'); ?>"/>
        <?php echo form_error('member_name[1]', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="member_address[1]">Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="member_address[1]" name="member_address[]" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo set_value('member_address[1]'); ?>"/>
        <?php echo form_error('member_address[1]', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
    </div>
```

I use the following to send them to their controller:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var form_data = $('#ajax-form').serialize();
    alert(form_data);

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('ajax_ci/ajax_check'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        async : false,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#form-name').append(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is the controller:

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_id[]', 'member ID', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_name[]', 'member name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_address[]', 'member password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo validation_errors();       
    } else {
        // connect to database
    }

} else {
    echo "Work on it! Don't give up!";
}
```

The screenshot below is currently what happens.
[image]
**But I want these errors to appear in their respective individual `form_errors`**
[image]

**Is this possible in my current setup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the validation errors that you return from the server, you will need to include information about which field failed. Probably an array of (fieldname=>errormsg). Your ajax response handler can then find the correct field and append the message to the DOM accordingly.